# Datetime and Time can't be used in the same program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time

So I'm writing a program with

```
import datetime
import time
```

I'm using time to record the time it takes the program to run, and I need to check the date so if the file is more than a certain age, don't process it.

I keep getting this error when trying to use these two classes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 563, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 498, in main
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'time'
shell returned 1
```

*Is it not possible to use both time and datetime in one program?*

Some of the code:

```
import PyPDF2
import re
import os
#Time testing
import time
#Using this to check if address is in proper format and to clean it up
import usaddress

#testing this one out
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import *
from dateutil.tz import *
from datetime import *

#Timer starts
start_time = time.time() #Error is referring to this line, line 498

#Opens 3 different files

#For file in folder parse it to text

#Writes some things to file

#Gets the date from the file

if date != None:
  fileDate = parse(date).year
  now = datetime.now()
  print now.year, now.month, now.day

#Ends the timer and prints the time to the console
print("--- %s seconds ---"  % round(time.time() - start_time, 2))
```

Comment: It cannot be reffering to that line. It is perfectly fine to use both. Just tried importing both and setting a `start_time` the way you do. You might have overwritten a method somewhere?

Comment: @Petar I'm pretty sure I didn't. Unless can another module overwrite a method?

Comment: If you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be much easier to debug.

Comment: Do you have a file called `time.py`? That might be causing a problem

Comment: @DavidG The rest of my code is just data manipulation from what I was able to get out of the file, then putting that data into CSV format, and writing to a bunch of files

Comment: Somewhere you must be overwriting `time`. It looks like something along the lines of `time = datetime.time` which then produces the error you have when you try to do `time.time()`

Comment: There is another issue here.  You are only importing datetime.  datetime.now() will throw an error, you need to call datetime.datetime.now() or import datetime from datetime.

Comment: **Don't** use `from datetime import *`, that is the cause of the problem

Comment: Sorry everyone, I should have included all of my imports

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Comment: @DavidG Those are the only places in my code I touch datetime and time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import *
from dateutil.tz import *
from datetime import *  # <<<< problems
```

First you are importing `datetime` and then you are importing everything from `datetime`.

Be explicit, and only import what you need.

`from datetime import datetime`

Then you can use it as `datetime.now` or whatever methods you may need.

As a rule of thumb, never import `*`. It causes exactly these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problems is:

```
from datetime import *
```

because it imports time from datetime. It's always better to import only what you need. But if you also really need this method you could do (for example):

```
from datetime import time as dt
```

That's why import * is dangerous...